# Cascading Select Box with React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a depending select box in which data will come in second select box as per the selection of first select box. I am using React JS.

Comment: do you have any code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes i have made simple onchange functions of each select boxes separately

Comment: handleChangestates = event => {
    const statesValid = event.target.value ? true : false;
    const submitValid = this.state.titleValid && this.state.descriptionValid && this.state.landmarkValid  && this.state.addressValid && this.state.amountValid && this.state.contactValid && this.state.rentPerValid && this.state.negotiateValid && this.state.propertyCategoryValid && this.state.tenantsValid && this.state.statesValid && this.state.cityValid
    this.setState({
       states: event.target.value,
       statesValid: statesValid,
       submitDisabled: !submitValid
       });
  };

Comment: handleChangecities = event => {
    const cityValid = event.target.value ? true : false;
    const submitValid = this.state.titleValid && this.state.descriptionValid && this.state.landmarkValid && this.state.addressValid && this.state.amountValid && this.state.contactValid && this.state.rentPerValid && this.state.negotiateValid && this.state.propertyCategoryValid && this.state.tenantsValid && this.state.statesValid && this.state.cityValid
    this.setState({
       cities: event.target.value,
       cityValid: cityValid,
       submitDisabled: !submitValid
      });
  };

Comment: Can u give a proper code of function of dependent Select box